# TransitionPropagation working as intended?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions, fragment-transitions

Let's say we have two fragments: `A` and `B`

`A` is visible, we want to replace it with `B`

`A` has an `exitTransition`, `B` has an `enterTransition`

Both transitions define a `TransitionPropagation` that they use to delay some animations. Those `TransitionPropagations` collect values that are needed for the start delay with `captureValues`.

What I expect when I commit my transaction from `A` to `B`:

1. `TransitionPropagation.captureValues` is called for all relevant views from `A`'s layout for the `exitTransition` of `A`
2. `TransitionPropagation.captureValues` is called for all relevant views from `B`'s layout for the `enterTransition` of `B`

What I see:
`TransitionPropagation.captureValues` is called for all relevant views from `A`'s layout for the `exitTransition` of `A` and then `TransitionPropagation.captureValues` is also called on the same Propagation for views that are defined in B's layout.

What is happening here? Why are views from `B` directed to the `exitTransition` of `A`?

Comment: And again the same problem... How can I know the start delay of a view that I had no chance to capture values for since it belongs to totally different transition?